# Can I run a 64 BIT SQL Server as 32 BIT?

Tags: sql-server

I have had multiple issues with the 64 BIT SQL Server I recentlly installed on a new personal machine.  I keep running into issues where applications don't work well with the 64 bit version but had no issues with the previous 32 bit version i used on an old machine.  Does anyone know of any options I might have other than uninstalling the 64 BIT version and reinstalling a 32 BIT version?

I am currently running....
2014 SQL SERVER EXPRESS 64 BIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you must uninstall SQL Server x64 and install the 32 bit edition.

Comment: Do you know if I can install the 32 BIT edition on top of the 64 and the install program will clean out the 64 BIT edition or will I need to do a full uninstall myself then start the reinstall.